# How to prevent Flux.jl from allocating the totality of my GPU's memory?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Is there any safeguard or option built into Flux.jl that I can set such that I don't accidentally end up allocating all of the available memory on my GPU? I don't see any sort of GPU options in the Flux.jl docs: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/gpu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, Flux.jl uses CUDA.jl as the interface to the GPU. CUDA.jl has an environment variable (which you can [read about in the docs](https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/usage/memory/#Environment-variables)) called `JULIA_CUDA_MEMORY_LIMIT` which can be used to:

> cap the amount of allocated GPU memory, in bytes.

Note that these environment variables should be set before importing packages; changing them at run time does not have any effect.

You can read more generally about memory management in Flux and CUDA here: https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/usage/memory/#Memory-management